# problem upgrading to ubuntu 18

Tags: upgrade

When I try to upgrade ubuntu 17 to 18 with this command 
`update-manager -c` 
It gives me a window of software updater and says 406.7MB will be downloaded. 
When I run this command

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk
```

It first shows that a new version is available but when I click on upgrade it shows this error before asking me to authenticate

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py:23: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated as I am always looking forward to expand my working knowledge of linux

Comment: Please correct the [Ubuntu version numbers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17941/250300). There is nothing like Ubuntu 17 or Ubuntu 18. While we can guess you are upgrading to 18.04, are you upgrading from 17.04 or 17.10? The former one is no more supported. The command `check-new-release-gtk` is most likely not intended for direct CLI usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: advice: if possible, you may prefer go for a fresh clean install of 18.04

Comment: I am upgrading from 17.10. And @Melebius whatever the commands I have used are taken from official Ubuntu website Ubuntu.com.